# Does every single table in a thesis need to be numbered?

Tags: formatting

In my thesis I'm analyzing the results of a linguistic survey in which a large number of words are discussed. I provide a small table with details of the statistical analysis for each word. All the tables look the same and there are as many as four of them on each page in one of the chapters. Should I also number each table and put all of them in the index of tables at the end of my thesis?

Comment: You could group related tables together as subtables under a single table number. Such as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294589/alignment-and-placing-of-subtables)

Comment: Probably. Have you read your school's dissertation formatting requirements? In my experience they have all kinds of details like this spelled out.

Comment: Probably.  Never underestimate the confusion that a reader may have particularly when there are lots of tables that aren't somehow annotated and discussed in text with clear way to find the table being referenced. Grouping tables that belong together, as mentioned by @mg4w,  also might be extremely helpful for reader.

Answer (score 2):

If the tables are not referenced in the thesis text, why are they in the body of the thesis?

I'd put them all into an appendix, number them, and provide an appropriate, terse label.  If there are specific ones that are referenced many times in the body of the thesis, you should include these in the body. Duplicate the in-body tables in the appendix.

If all the tables are in an appendix, there is no need for an index of tables, but it would depend on the norms for your subject area.